# Issue with converting data type varchar to numeric. Best approach?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am attempting to a convert one of the values that go into my insert. I am getting an error converting data type `varchar` to `numeric`. How else could I further justify this? Am I better off using a cast? I'm a bit new to this so I know who which is the best method to take.

Here is the line

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 3), 
        AVG(CASE R.ITEM 
               WHEN 'KD_ITEM' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 3), R.RN2) * 100.00 
               ELSE NULL 
            END)) AS [KD_ITEMAVG]
```

which it is failing on with an error of:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: I would recommend that once you figure this out you change the datatype to decimal(10, 3) so you don't have to keep fighting bad data in a column that should only have numbers.

Comment: You need to find out the offending value or values. They could be syntactically wrong, or too big to fit in `DECIMAL(10,3)`. Try doing `SELECT R.RN2 FROM ... WHERE R.ITEM = 'KD_ITEM' ORDER BY R.RN2' and see if you can spot the problem.

Comment: @Brad You do realize that your version of sql server is **very** old. You ask about best method but do not discuss your goal. And "best", like pretty, is in the eye of the beholder. Searching will find suggestions for a 2008 try_cast equivalent. But as others have said, your schema is the source of the problem. The "best" approach is to fix that so that you don't have to handle this in every query that accesses your table.

Answer (score 0):

`CAST()` and `CONVERT()` do the same thing, except `CONVERT()` has an optional third argument.

If you have potentially invalid data, use `TRY_CONVERT()` instead of `CONVERT()`:

```
TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),
            AVG(CASE R.ITEM WHEN 'KD_ITEM' THEN TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3), R.RN2)*100.00 
                END)
           ) AS [KD_ITEMAVG]
```

Comment: Is decimal not a function that is built under TRY_CONVERT? I am getting a 'DECIMAL' is not a recognized built-in function name due to changing the convert.

Comment: `DECIMAL` is the name of a data type, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql)(SQL Server 2012 and above):

```
TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),
            AVG(CASE R.ITEM WHEN 'KD_ITEM' 
                THEN TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),R.RN2)*100.00 
                ELSE NULL END))
AS [KD_ITEMAVG]
```

Comment: Is decimal not a function that is built under TRY_CONVERT? I am getting a 'DECIMAL' is not a recognized built-in function name due to changing the convert.

Comment: @Brad `SELECT @@version`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4042.0 (X64) 
 Mar 26 2015 21:18:04 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)